# How to programatically define a static array in Rust?

Tags: rust, static

I'm trying to make a piece of my code more performant by using a static lookup table to avoid calls to a slow function, something like this:

```
fn my_slow_fn(x: usize) -> f64 {...}

const TABLE_SIZE: usize = 100;
static TABLE_VALUES: [f64; TABLE_SIZE] = (0..TABLE_SIZE)
  .map(my_slow_fn)
  .collect::<Vec<_>>()
  .try_into()
  .unwrap();

fn my_fast_fn(x: f64) -> f64 {
  let table_idx = get_table_idx(x)
  TABLE_VALUES[table_idx] // much faster than calling my_slow_fn(table_idx)
}
```

But the above code isn't legal because I can't make calls to non-constant functions when creating a static variable. How can I cleanly initialize this lookup table exactly once for the duration of the program?

My crate is a library, so I have no `main` function.

Comment: Can you use code generation or make `my_slow_fn()` `const fn`? These are the simplest options.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make `my_slow_fn` `const`, since it uses floating point arithmetic. Also, the `map` and `collect` functions are not `const` either. By code generation do you mean a macro?

Comment: You can workaround `map()` and `collect()`, this is not the problem. By code generation I mean either a macro or just a simple code that outputs code into file.

Comment: Could `my_slow_fn` be evaluated at compile time, theoretically? E.g. does it have any side effects? Secondly, could it be extracted from your existing code into a `proc_macro` subcrate?

Comment: Otherwise things that come to my mind: an `unsafe` initialization at the beginning of your `main()`; a `[AtomicF64::Nan; TABLE_SIZE]` array that gets filled lazily and used as a kind of caching; `lazy_static` (which is probably slow), `std::sync::Once` (which is also probably slow)

Comment: `lazy_static` and `once_cell` are far from slow, but if it helps, I just published a crate for lazy-init then free access with a ZST token: https://docs.rs/init-token (I hope it is sound).

Comment: My crate is a library, so I have no `main` function (edited). I would rather not create a whole nother crate or resort to a `build.rs` or procedural macro for this (but `macro_rules` would be simple enough). But it looks like I can use a simple `while` loop if I can somehow make the function `const`.

Comment: Do you want the table to be filled at compile time or at runtime? 'Cause there are a couple of runtime options if you don't manage to make it const. Although none of them are great, especially if you have a library; because every function call would then have to contain a check of whether or not the table was already initialized.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman So if I get it right, you only have the `Once` overhead when getting the token, and then you can get the data via `Deref` from the token? That's a cool idea.

Comment: If you cannot create a macro, nor can you make the function `const`, you have to initialize it at runtime. The main questions here are: can you afford a little check (really unimportant unless you have super perf-critical code), and what do you want to do in `my_slow_fn()`?

Comment: @Finomnis Yep. I have not invented the pattern, I just needed a free-access runtime-initialized `static` for a project of mine and found nothing, so I went ahead and created my own.

Comment: Maybe post it on r/Rust to get some traction for it. Although this is definitely off-topic now :D

Comment: @ChayimFriedman your docs don't show actual usage of the static. I'd recommend adding that

Comment: @PitaJ They do on the macros themselves. Perhaps I need to add in lib.rs too.